# What typeface is used on the AMOK album cover?

Tags: typography, font-identification

Just out of curiosity. I know it's designed by Stanley Donwood. It looks like Futura with the M reaching slightly below the baseline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are speaking about the cover attached below (for other's reference), yes, this is Futura.

The middle angle of M always slightly falls under the baseline in any version of Futura. Here, this effect is emphasized with addition of double outer stroke which falls under the baseline even further.

[image]

Comment: Also note that in most typefaces, many of the characters extend slightly below or above the baseline. It's a subtle thing to optically adjust the characters to they 'look' equal in height (even if they are technically not).